# Best format to store data

Tags: python, parsing, format

In my program I read data from a file and then parse it. The format is

```
data   |   data   |   data   |   data   |   data
```

What is a better format to store data in ?
It must be easily parsed by python and easy to use.

Comment: the file stores information like this:
f151 | tun0 | 00:00:00:00:00:00 | 10.8.2.0 | server

and then the program parses the data, stores each "column" in a variable/list and then I print the lists in aligned columns so the output looks like this

f151    tun0    00:00:00:00:00:00    10.8.2.0    server
f164    tun0    00:00:00:00:00:00    10.8.2.1    client

Comment: Do you need to transfer data between apps or languages, or to databases? How big is the data set?

Answer (score 3):

JSON - http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

CSV - http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csvreader

XML - there's a selection to choose from depending what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [pickling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-pickle-module). You can serialise and write objects to a file and then read them back later.

If the data needs to be read by programs written in other languages consider using [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your data format is fine if you don't need to use the pipe (`|`) character anywhere. Databases often use pipe-delimited data and it's easily parsed.

CSV (comma-separated values) are a more universal format, but not much different that pipe-separated. Both have some limitations, but for simple data they work fine.

XML is good if you have complex data, but it's a more complicated format. Complicated doesn't necessarily mean better if your needs are simple, so you'd need to think about the data you want to store, and if you want to transfer it to other apps or languages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the experience with JSON and CSV and both worked just fine. but in my opinion, CSV was a bit easier to work with

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).